# Querying for keywords in photos using DynamoDB and PHP

Tags: php, amazon-dynamodb

Requirement: I'm storing photos in S3 and want the user to be able to lookup all photos that contain a keyword they type in on a webpage.

My solution: I have created 2 tables:
**tblPhotos:**
Primary Key=HashKey: PhotoID
Fields: 
PhotoID, 
S3Location

**tblKeywords:** 
Primary Key=HashKey (HashID) and RangeKey (Keyword)
Fields: 
HashID (always set to 1), 
Keyword (one big string; the keyword followed by PhotoID)
S3Location

I'm using the following php code to find all records that have my keyword in it:

```
$table_name = 'tblKeywords';
$keywordresponse = $dynamodb->query(array(
    'TableName'    => $table_name,
    'HashKeyValue' => array(AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => '1'),
    'RangeKeyCondition' => array(
        'ComparisonOperator' => AmazonDynamoDB::CONDITION_BEGINS_WITH,
        'AttributeValueList' => array(
                 array(AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING => $_GET['sSearch'])
                                 ),
                         )
                         ));
if ($keywordresponse->isOK())
{
     foreach ($keywordresponse->body->Items as $item)
     {
          $aaData[] = array(
    'Keyword' => (string) $item->Keyword->{AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING},
        'S3Location' => (string) $item->S3Location->{AmazonDynamoDB::TYPE_STRING}
                       );
     }
     echo json_encode(array('keywordstatus' => 1, 'aaData' => $aaData));
}
else
{
    echo json_encode(array('keywordstatus' => 0));
}
```

As you can see I'm passing sSearch as the keyword to filter results on. My question is, do you know a better way to achieve this filtering of records using DynamoDB query? I'm trying to avoid a scan as its very inefficient, although my solution above whilst it works doesn't seem particularly elegant!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your primary goal is to be able to return all the photos for a given key word I think the following schema would make more sense:

HashKey = Keyword

RangeKey = PhotoID

Additional possible fields: S3Name (if it is not the same as PhotoID)

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I think it will only let me have one 'row' per primary key? In other words, only one record per Keyword. I would expect hundreds of photoIDs to have the same Keyword. Unless I'm missing something?

Comment: I should have called the first part of the key the "Hash" not the "Primary" (edited above)... When you have a "Hash and Range Type Primary Key" the first hash value is assumed to have duplicates... The combination of hash and range is the unique "Primary Key" value...

Comment: Ah interesting - I'd tried it the other way round, with PhotoID being the hashkey and Keyword being the rangekey which didn't work. 1 PhotoID may have multiple keywords, so I'll need to test to see if it copes with that. I'll try and let you know, thanks!